# Trying to make a "save as" form using php's "file_put_contents" and javascript... "Filename cannot be empty"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a "save as" feature using javascript and php.  In the html I use:

```
<textarea id="filename" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea>    
<li class ="add" onclick="js:saveas()" >save</li>
```

Then with inline javascript I do this to get the filename and dynamically generated dom:

```
<script>
function saveas() {
   $.post('write.php', { name : $('#filename').val() });
   $.post('write.php', { dom : $('html').html() });
    }

 </script>
```

Then over in "write.php"...

```
<?php
$name = urldecode($_POST['name']);
$dom = urldecode($_POST['dom']);
file_put_contents($name, $dom);

?>
```

But the console says:

```
[30-Aug-2012 15:45:22] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dom in /Users/J/Documents/test7/test7/write.php on line 3

[30-Aug-2012 15:45:22] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /Users/J/Documents/test7/test7/write.php on line 2

[30-Aug-2012 15:45:22] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents() [<a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in /Users/J/Documents/test7/test7/write.php on line 4
```

And it creates the file with the correct name but it's empty, zero bytes.  However if I hardcode the filename, like this:

```
file_put_contents('foo.html', $dom);
```

everything works the way it should, though I still get the notices.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security issues aside (what you are doing is **not** secure), you are sending two different POSTs to *write.php*.

You want to send both values in 1 request:

```
$.post('write.php', {
    name : $('#filename').val(),
    dom : $('html').html()
});
```

And did I mention, what you are doing is **not** secure?

Comment: That did it!  There's no database, it's going to a node.js static site generator.  Are you saying someone could put some crazy malware on my server?

Comment: Anything that writes a user-controlled filename with user-controlled content to the server is a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing 2 `$.post` calls?  You need to send both variables in one call.

```
$.post('write.php', {
    name : $('#filename').val(),
    dom : $('html').html()
});
```

Comment: Both of you answered correctly at the same time, I gave it to the other guy because he had fewer points.  Thanks though!